# Filter a List of Files by Date String

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I have a list of files:

```
file_list <- c("C:\\Users\\uname\\files/DailyOpenOrders_NET_20160922.csv", 
"C:\\Users\\uname\\files/DailyOpenOrders_NET_20160923.csv", 
"C:\\Users\\uname\\files/DailyOpenOrders_NET_20160927.csv", 
"C:\\Users\\uname\\files/DailyOpenOrders_NET_20160928.csv", 
"C:\\Users\\uname\\files/DailyOpenOrders_NET_20160929.csv", 
"C:\\Users\\uname\\files/DailyOpenOrders_NET_20160930.csv"
)
```

And a parsed list of those file name's dates, filtered only for the dates that are mondays:

```
file_dates_mon <- structure(list(file_dates = c("20161003", "20161010", "20161017", "20161024", "20161031", "20161107"), weekday = c("Monday", "Monday", 
"Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday")), .Names = c("file_dates", 
"weekday"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I attempted using `str_detect(file_list,file_dates_mon$file_dates)` to attempt to filter the file list down to the dates that are monday only.
The intent is to pre filter the file list, rather than merge 361 files then filter by date after.

Is there a way to pre-filter the list based on the dates in `file_dates_mon`?  `file_list` is the result of

```
dir<- choose.dir()
file_list<-list.files(dir,full.names = TRUE,pattern="DailyOpenOrders_NET_*")
```

Comment: When you tried `str_detect` what went wrong? It seems to work with me.

Comment: @RuiBarradas - The result only returned one TRUE match out of the 361.

Comment: @PKumar That returned a failure to parse, no formats detected. Again, the intent is to filter the list of file names, where the date is a certain day of week, in this case Monday.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that `str_detect` is vectorized over pattern or string. Not both at the same time.

some patterns:

```
filter_mon <- c("20160929", "20160927")
```

now check `str_detect`:

```
library(stringr)
str_detect(file_list, filter_mon)
#output
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

just the first pattern is matched in all strings. One `TRUE` is returned.

One way around that is to run `str_detect` for each `file_dates_mon$file_dates` (or as in this example `filter_mon`) and then `Reduce` the logical vectors:

```
file_list[Reduce("|", lapply(filter_mon, function(x) str_detect(file_list, x)))]

#output
[1] "C:\\Users\\uname\\files/DailyOpenOrders_NET_20160927.csv" "C:\\Users\\uname\\files/DailyOpenOrders_NET_20160929.csv"
```

`grepl` is also an alternative

```
file_list[Reduce("|", lapply(filter_mon, function(x) grepl(x, file_list)))]
```

Comment: I attempted a version of both of these earlier, but this worked. Will try to find what the differences were.